# <v-navigation-drawer>がfooterの横にまで来てしまっている

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

ある要素に設定するスタイルのheightの値を動的に設定したいと考えています。具体的には、一番下までスクロールしていた時は、heightの高さを77.5%、まったくフッター要素が見えていないときは、100%,フッターが見えていた場合は、見えている数値分100%から高さを引きたいと考えています。
下記handleScrollにて色々と試してみたのですが、うまいこと高さを調整することが出来ません。調節する方法がありましたら教えて頂けましたら幸いです

```
.v-navigation-drawer {
  height: 77.5% !important;
}
```

以下はコードの全文になります。

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Header />
    <!-- <TableofContents /> -->
    <v-navigation-drawer width="300" border="r" app> test </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <slot />
      </v-container>
      <NavigationLink />
    </v-main>
    <v-footer border="t">
      <v-row justify="center" no-gutters>
        <AppThemeToggle />
        <v-col class="primary lighten-2 py-4 text-center white--text" cols="12">
          <strong
            >Copyright {{ new Date().getFullYear() }} vuetify
            Corporation</strong
          >
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

[image: スクリーンショット]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76918206/positional-relationship-between-footer-and-navigation/76918981?noredirect=1#comment135615260_76918981
こちらのURL先(英語版のスタオバ)で頂いた回答で解決することが出来ました。